# Does a DDL in Oracle affect other transactions?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, ddl

I understand that DDL statements in Oracle have an implicit commit before and after the statement, which obviously affects the current transaction.

However, does a DDL statement in any way affect other transactions running against that table (assuming the change is compatible with the DML running against the table)?

For example, if I decide to `modify` a `varchar2(10)` columnn to `varchar2(20)`, or add a new column altogether, or drop an obsolete, no longer used column -- are other transactions going to be happy about it, or is there going to be any sort of contention or interruption of running transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://orainternals.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/lock-table-followed-by-ddl/) explains how DDL statements work and how they need exclusive table locks, which plays out nicely when there are transactions running against the table. To summarize:

If the table cannot be locked due to another transaction having a lock on the table

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

would be thrown. If the DDL manages to acquire the lock, obviously, any other transaction will block at the point where it needs a lock on the table, until the DDL finishes.

Additionally, since 11g, it is possible to enqueue DDL statements in FIFO order with other statements to get a lock on a table:

```
declare
begin
      -- We really want to drop that column and so wait for 1800 seconds.
      execute immediate 'alter session set ddl_lock_timeout=1800';
      execute immediate 'alter table t1 drop column n5 ';
exception
  when others then
     dbms_output.put_line(' No luck ');
     dbms_output.put_line(' SQL code'||sqlcode||','|| 'error '||sqlerrm );
end;
/
```

In older versions of Oracle, it could be a challenge to perform this task on a heavily used table.